# Powershell scripts open and close many windows without running

Tags: powershell, windows-10

The problem I am having is that any powershell script that I try to run, either by double clicking or using "powershell /path/to/script" from cmd, will open a window, then  close, then open another window, then close, and so on... The code never actually runs though.

I have set the execution policy to what it needs to be to allow powershell scripts to run. I have tried running as administrator. I have tried this on 2 separate computers running Windows 10. I've tried using these 3 scripts as test scripts with the same result:

1

```
write-host("hello")
```

2

```
write-host("hello")
cmd /c pause
```

3

```
cmd /c pause
```

Has anyone seen this behavior and know how to fix it?

Comment: Invoke with `powershell -noexit -file ...` to keep the session open, so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: What is the name of your script file?

Comment: Both of these comments helped!
after -noexit, I saw:
"Processing -File './test.psl' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again."

I assumed the extension was .psL. Apparently it's .ps1 (one) .... Definitely not obvious.... thanks for the help!!!